# The definition of $\binom{n}{r}$ considering $r>n$ is allowed?

Tags: combinatorics, soft-question, definition, binomial-coefficients

After reading the post: [Parameters of a Binomial Coefficient](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1993095/parameters-of-a-binomial-coefficient). I still have some confusion about the discrete definition(s) of $\binom{n}{r}$. I'm only interested in the case where $n, r\in\Bbb Z$, not the extended version of $\binom{n}{r}$ represented by Gamma function. (I would like to learn this approach when I'm more fluent at Calculus / continuous sort of things.)

I used to thought the definition is $\Large\binom{n}{r}:=\frac{n!}{r!(n-r)!}$, because it is more concise in a way that it has less *combinatorial meaning components*, i.e. only three: $n!, r!, (n-r)!$, than the falling factorial way $\Large\binom{n}{r} :=\frac{n(n-1)\cdots(n-r+1)}{r(r-1)\cdots1}$, which has $2r$ components, and it's hard to read a long formula with numbers scattered around. But the one I prefer can't define $\binom{3}{4}$ by the formula $\frac{3!}{4!(3-4)!}$, since you can't choose $4$ out of $3$ so it should be zero, but this would mean $\frac{1}{(-1)!}=0$, I consider this combinatorially meaningless. While the other one can define it properly: $\binom{3}{4}=\frac{3\cdot2\cdot1\cdot0}{4\cdot3\cdot2\cdot1}$.

So what's the formal definition of it that can deal with the case $r>n$ by formula, without define negative factorial to be zero? (Although I don't know whether a negative factorial would be useful in the future.)

Comment: You can use the standard notation for the [falling factorial](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Falling_factorial_power), i.e. $\binom{n}{r} = \frac{n^\underline{r}}{r!}$, as explained [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_coefficient#Multiplicative_formula).

Comment: I prefer Pascal's triangle where $n\ge 0$ using $\binom{0}{r}:=0^r$ and the recursion $\binom{n+1}{r+1}=\binom{n}{r}+\binom{n}{r+1}$

Comment: @Somos: Actually I used what you wrote to guess the value of $\binom{n}{-1}$, since $\binom{n}{0}=\binom{n-1}{0}+\binom{n-1}{-1}$.

Comment: I should have used $\binom{0}{r}:=\delta_{0r}$ with [Kronecker delta function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kronecker_delta).

Comment: $\displaystyle {-1 \choose 3} = -1$ for example.

Answer (score 2):

The usual convention is that binomial coefficients which are "out of range" equal zero.

But there's another convention. If $k$ is a nonnegative integer, then
$$\binom{n}k=\frac1{k!}n(n-1)\cdots(n-k+1)$$
for integers $n\ge k$.
So we could define $\binom{x}k$ as the polynomial
$$\binom{x}k=\frac1{k!}x(x-1)\cdots(x-k+1)$$
of degree $k$. Its zeros are $0,1,\ldots,k-1$.

With either convention, $\binom 34=0$.

Answer (score 2):

For $n\ge0$, $\binom{n}{r}$ is the number of size-$r$ subsets of $\{1,\,\cdots,\,n\}$, regardless of $r$. If $0\le r\le n$, we can prove$$\binom{n}{r}=\binom{n}{n-r}=\frac{\prod_{j=n-r+1}^nj}{r!}.$$We can maintain this in an extension to $n<0$, viz.$$\binom{-m}{r}:=(-1)^m\binom{m+r-1}{r}=(-1)^m\binom{m+r-1}{m-1}$$for $m:=-n>0$. In particular, this is nonzero iff $r\ge0$. But to unite these cases, we can define $\binom{n}{r}$ more generally as the $x^r$ coefficient in $(1+x)^n$, as per the [generalized binomial theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_theorem#Newton%27s_generalized_binomial_theorem):$$\binom{n}{r}:=[x^r](1+x)^n=[x^{-1}]\frac{(1+x)^n}{x^{r+1}}=\oint_{|z=1|}\frac{(1+z)^ndz}{2\pi iz^{r+1}}.$$

Answer (score 1):

Personally I think it is best to define using the Gamma function, that is
$${}_x \mathrm{C}_y=\frac{\Gamma(x+1)}{\Gamma(y+1)\Gamma(x-y+1)}$$
Since this takes care of the "negative factorial". For real $\alpha$ and an integer $k$, Wikipedia cites $${}_\alpha \mathrm{C}_k = \frac{\operatorname{Fact}(\alpha,k,\downarrow)}{k!}$$
With $\operatorname{Fact}(\alpha,k,\downarrow)$ being the falling factorial,
$$\operatorname{Fact}(\alpha,k,\downarrow)=\prod_{j=0}^{k-1}(\alpha-j)$$
But it is easy to see that this is always $0$ if $\alpha \in \mathbb{N}$ and $k>\alpha$.

Answer (score 1):

If you interpret $\binom n r$ combinatorially as the number of subsets of cardinality $r$ in a set of cardinality $n,$ then the expression is defined only when $n$ and $r$ are cardinalities, thus in $\{0,1,2,3,\ldots\}$ (where that set specified in $\{\text{braces}\}$ does or does not include cardinalities of infinite sets depending on what you want to do). In that case $\binom n r=0$ when $r>n$ because the number of subsets of cardinality $r$ in a set of cardinality $n$ is $0$ in that case.

There is also the use of these expressions in the expansion of powers of binomials, when the exponent is not an integer:

$$
(x+y)^n = \sum_{k=0}^\infty \binom n k x^k y^{n-k} \quad \text{if either } n\in\{0,1,2,\ldots\} \text{ or } \left| \frac x y \right| <1
$$
where
$$
\binom n k = \frac{n(n-1)(n-2) \cdots (n-k+1)}{k!} \\
\text{ and $n$ need not be an integer and need not be positive.}
$$
In this binomial theorem, the identity $\dbinom n k = \dfrac{n!}{k!(n-k)!}$ does not hold if factorials are defined only for nonnegative integers. If $\ge0,$ then one can still define factorials thus:
$$
r! = \int_0^\infty x^r e^{-x}\,dx.
$$
The idea of $\dfrac 1 {(-1)!}=0$ can make sense if one analytically continues this definition of factorial and then construes the expression to mean $\displaystyle \lim_{r\,\to\,-1} \frac 1 {r!}.$ You don't even need the concept of analytic continuation to do this if you use the identity $r!(r+1) = (r+1)!$ to define factorials of negative non-integers.

And for negative integer values of $n,$ one can say $n!=\infty$ provided one takes this to mean neither $+\infty$ nor $-\infty$ but rather the $\infty$ that is at both ends of the real line.

Answer (score 1):

For integral (even complex) $n$ and integral $r$ the following definition holds:

\begin{align*}
\binom{n}{r}=
\begin{cases}
\frac{n(n-1)\cdots (n-r+1)}{r!}=\frac{n^{\underline{r}}}{r!}&\quad r\geq 0\\
0&\quad r<0
\end{cases}
\end{align*}

See for instance formula (5.1) in chapter *Binomial Coefficients* of *[Concrete Mathematics](https://www.csie.ntu.edu.tw/%7Er97002/temp/Concrete%20Mathematics%202e.pdf)*
by D.E. Knuth, R.L. Graham and O. Patashnik.